# Работа со StringBuilder Java

Tags: java, строки

#### Добрый день

---

Как многим известно, в `Java` использовать такую конструкцию нежелательно

```
"Hello" + "Name" + "Surname" + etc.;
//или же
String text = "Hello";
text += "Name";
text += "Surname";
text += etc...;
```

И стоит использовать в данных случаях `StringBuilder`, правда у меня появился вопрос на счет этого, хотелось бы узнать, правильно ли я использую его?

```
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append("Name: " + this.getName());
    builder.append("\nSurname: " + this.getSurname());
    builder.append("\nAge: " + this.getAge());
    builder.append(this.isSex() ? "\nWoman " : "\nMan ");
    builder.append("\nCourse: " + this.course);
    builder.append("\nFaculty: " + this.faculty);
    builder.append("\nGroup: " + this.group);
    String result = new String(builder);
    return result;
}
```

Смотря на код, думаю что я использую его не правильно... Если это так, подскажите как нужно, и что желательно использовать в таких ситуациях?

Comment: и еще на `return builder.toString()` замени

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Операции конкатенации в append замените продолжением цепочки вызовов самого append, дабы минимизировать создание новых строк типа String:

```
builder.append("\nAge: ").append(this.getAge());
```

и т.д.
А в целом - все нормально.
Да и вопрос оптимизации в данном случае сомнителен, хотя и не исключается...

Comment: Все в одну строку что ли?

Comment: @KryTer_NexT а вы считаете что Ваш код создает еще какие то переменные?) Тот код, что я привел - делает ровно тоже самое что и Ваш;)
Я имел ввиду замену конкатенации ( знак " + ", создание новой строки типа String) на вызов метода append() в Вашем коде.
В Вашем варианте происходит так:
"\nAge: " + this.getAge() - создается лишняя новая строка String. Цепочка вызовов append() убирает эту "проблему".

Comment: Аааа понял) Спасибо))

Answer (score 2):

```
"Hello" + "Name" + "Surname" + etc.; // все ок, будет преобразовано в sb.append(...).append(...). ... А сумма строк-констант заранее склеется еще на этапе перехода в байт-код. Я бы не сказал, что данный код плохой.


String text = "Hello";
text += "Name";
text += "Surname";
text += etc...;  // крайне не эффективный код, перед каждой операцией сложения будет выполняться преобразование в StringBuilder, а затем снова в String. Также, заранее не можем сделать никаких вычислений.
```

Второй блок (непосредственно с вашим кодом) уже разобрали.

Answer (score 2):

На самом деле, можете объединять строки через `+`, если это обычные поля, а не вызов метода c какими то `side-effect'ами`. Компилятор достаточно умен, и такие места он заменяет на `java.lang.StringBuilder`.

Можно убедиться в этом, рассмотрев следующий пример:

```
public class Man {
  private String name;
  private String surname;

  public String firstMethod() {
    return name + surname;
  }

  public String secondMethod() {
     return new StringBuilder()
            .append(name)
            .append(surname)
            .toString();
}}
```

Посмотрим, какой генерируется байт код. В детали можете не вникать, тут самое главное - это пояснения к нему.

```
public class ru.izebit.Man
  minor version: 0
  major version: 52
  flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_SUPER
Constant pool:
   #1 = Methodref          #9.#25         // java/lang/Object."":()V
   #2 = Class              #26            // java/lang/StringBuilder
   #3 = Methodref          #2.#25         // java/lang/StringBuilder."":()V
   #4 = Fieldref           #8.#27         // ru/izebit/Man.name:Ljava/lang/String;
   #5 = Methodref          #2.#28         // java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
   #6 = Fieldref           #8.#29         // ru/izebit/Man.surname:Ljava/lang/String;
   #7 = Methodref          #2.#30         // java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
   #8 = Class              #31            // ru/izebit/Man
   #9 = Class              #32            // java/lang/Object
  #10 = Utf8               name
  #11 = Utf8               Ljava/lang/String;
  #12 = Utf8               surname
  #13 = Utf8               
  #14 = Utf8               ()V
  #15 = Utf8               Code
  #16 = Utf8               LineNumberTable
  #17 = Utf8               LocalVariableTable
  #18 = Utf8               this
  #19 = Utf8               Lru/izebit/Man;
  #20 = Utf8               firstMethod
  #21 = Utf8               ()Ljava/lang/String;
  #22 = Utf8               secondMethod
  #23 = Utf8               SourceFile
  #24 = Utf8               Man.java
  #25 = NameAndType        #13:#14        // "":()V
  #26 = Utf8               java/lang/StringBuilder
  #27 = NameAndType        #10:#11        // name:Ljava/lang/String;
  #28 = NameAndType        #33:#34        // append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
  #29 = NameAndType        #12:#11        // surname:Ljava/lang/String;
  #30 = NameAndType        #35:#21        // toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
  #31 = Utf8               ru/izebit/Man
  #32 = Utf8               java/lang/Object
  #33 = Utf8               append
  #34 = Utf8               (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
  #35 = Utf8               toString
{
  public ru.izebit.Man();
    descriptor: ()V
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=1, locals=1, args_size=1
         0: aload_0
         1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."":()V
         4: return
      LineNumberTable:
        line 4: 0
      LocalVariableTable:
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
            0       5     0  this   Lru/izebit/Man;

  public java.lang.String firstMethod();
    descriptor: ()Ljava/lang/String;
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=2, locals=1, args_size=1
         0: new           #2                  // class java/lang/StringBuilder
         3: dup
         4: invokespecial #3                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder."":()V
         7: aload_0
         8: getfield      #4                  // Field name:Ljava/lang/String;
        11: invokevirtual #5                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
        14: aload_0
        15: getfield      #6                  // Field surname:Ljava/lang/String;
        18: invokevirtual #5                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
        21: invokevirtual #7                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
        24: areturn
      LineNumberTable:
        line 9: 0
      LocalVariableTable:
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
            0      25     0  this   Lru/izebit/Man;

  public java.lang.String secondMethod();
    descriptor: ()Ljava/lang/String;
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=2, locals=1, args_size=1
         0: new           #2                  // class java/lang/StringBuilder
         3: dup
         4: invokespecial #3                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder."":()V
         7: aload_0
         8: getfield      #4                  // Field name:Ljava/lang/String;
        11: invokevirtual #5                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
        14: aload_0
        15: getfield      #6                  // Field surname:Ljava/lang/String;
        18: invokevirtual #5                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
        21: invokevirtual #7                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
        24: areturn
      LineNumberTable:
        line 13: 0
        line 14: 11
        line 15: 18
        line 16: 21
        line 13: 24
      LocalVariableTable:
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
            0      25     0  this   Lru/izebit/Man;
}
```

Как мы видим, в обоих методах используется `java.lang.StringBuilder`.

Касаемо вашего кода, он вполне корректен, за исключением излишней многословности. `StringBuilder` позволяет писать более лаконичнее, используя `fluent style`

Comment: Для случая конкатенации 3-ёх и более полей\переменных в одном выражении будет также генерироваться единственный StringBuilder или для каждой отдельной конкатенации будет создаваться новый?

Comment: От количества строк не зависит, зависит от того, что объединяете, например "hello "+getWorld() не будет оптимизироваться. Да, будет только один StringBuilder

Comment: Можно ли где-нибудь прочитать подробнее, почему это не работает с вызовом методов?

Comment: @Roxio0 в этом докладе Леша Шипелев упоминает про эту оптимизацию https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SZFe3m1DV1A

Answer (score 1):

Да метод в `StringBuilder.append()` вернет `instance` `StringBuilder`, тоесть можно делать как указал 'ep1demic'

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("")
  .append("")
  .append("");
```

еще лучше не использовать `this.getSurname()`, вместо этого просто писать

```
this.surname
```

и `sb.getString();` вместо `new String(sb);`

Comment: нет такого метода `getString()` у `StringBuilder`... А насчет методов `this.getSurname, this.getName();` была из-за того что я инкапсулировал в родительском классе что и пришлось написать так, но уже убрал модификатор `private` открыл полный доступ :)

Comment: сори toString(); нельзя убирать модификатор private, или замените на protected, либо юзайте методы parent класса.

Comment: Ну так я юзал его методы, вы написали что убери `this.getSurname();` и сделай `this.surname`

Comment: ну this это указатель на текущий класс. если можно делайте this.name чем this.getName(), так корректней.

Comment: ааааа, просто прописать `.append(getName())` ?

Comment: ага, но мне кажется можно сделать филды родительского класса с модификатором protected и юзать или super.name или name

Comment: Хмм, ты прав) Это уже завтра сделаю) Спасибо за советы